# Place two outbound calls and bridge them, with UCMA 4

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

Does anyone know which approach that should be used to place two outbound calls from a UCMA application, and bound these two together?

Case:
The UCMA application will call caller A (Alice) and when answered by Alice, the app should transfer the call to caller B (Bob), or establish a new call to Bob, and bridge the calls together between Alice and Bob. I still want the control (SIP) to flow to my UCMA app, but the audio stream directly between Alice and Bob.

Should I:
(A)
- Establish a call to Alice, and when answered, make a selftransfer of that call with Bob as target (by a B2BUA)?

(B)
- Establish the call to Alice, when answered establish a call to Bob, then bridging these two calls in some way?

UPDATE:
Please note that its the UCMA app that has to place a call to Alice, and then transfer the call to Bob.
If I'm placing a new AudioVideoCall to Alice from my app, and after answer placing a transfer through a 'self-transfer' and a BackToBackCall, then Bob receives the call, but as soon as Bob answers, the call gets terminated!?

If Alice is calling my app, and catch by an 'OnCallReceived' event of my Application Endpoint, and following the same steps (self-transfer the call to Bob, with a B2BCall, and Bob answers the call), then the call is transfered correctly, without getting terminated. Whats the dirrence?

Note! I think I added some confusion to the terms here. I earlier wrote that I wanted to RTP from alice and bob to go through the app, but what I meant was the SIP signaling. The RTP (media stream) has to flow between Alice and Bob ofcause.

Comment: you have to use `BackToBackCall`, when Alice calls to your application, the application will create `BackToBackCallSettings` from the inbound call (alice) and `BackToBackCallSettings` for the outbound call(bob).

Comment: I tried to place a call to Alice, and then self-transfer it to Bob, which is actually doing a B2B (BackToBackCall) in the selftransfer method. Please note that Alice ain't calling the app, but the app is calling alice. My test seems to work, or at least sort of. Its calling Alice, and when answered placeing a call to Bob. But it seems that as soon as Bob answers, the call gets terminated??

Comment: Yes excatly. I want my app to call Alice, then Bob, combine them (B2BCall) and leave the audio stream between them, and keep the RTP control between the two end-users and the UCMA app

Comment: as described in [back to back call scenarios](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC504227.jpg), you can bridge the IM calls but when using BackToBack Call, what you are trying to achive, its not possible..

Comment: What is it that make it impossible? I mean, I can't see any difference between receiving a call from caller to my app, or establishing a new AudioVideoCall from my app to caller? In both cases I have a active call that I can use as incoming call leg for a B2B call.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I didn't make it cleara enough. The whole idea with using B2B by the UCMA app is, that the SIP signaling is still flowing from the end-user to the UCMA app, while audio stream is directly between them. Thats the overall purpose of my case. According to Unified Communication written by Michael Greenlee, a BackToBackCall configuration can consist of two idle calls. But I don't know if this is possible in UCMA 4? Right now, if I'm doing supervised transfer of a newly established call, both end-users are receiving my call, but it gets terminated right after Bob answer, as in my update

Comment: the behavior which you are getting is the actual behavior of the sample application for B2B call, UCMA app will terminate one the call between two users is established.

Comment: Thats ok. But if I'm doing a supervised transfers (call replacement) with an incoming call, to another uri target, then the B2BCall will establish on the existing call, calling Bob and made following state change 'state has changed from Transferring to Terminating, reason: CallTransferred.', but Alice and Bob can now talk with each others until I shutdown my app (due to sip signaling still flows to the app), or they hangup.
If I do the same with a call that I created from the App to Alice (BeginEstablish on a new AV-call), then when transfering to Bob, the same state changes is reported.

Comment: I have been trying to solve the exact same problem as well, but besides this question I have not found anything helpful. Do you (@SagarPilkhwal) know whether such a thing is even possible to be done with UCMA (I'm actually looking for a solution using UCWA, but I'd be interested in whether this scenario can be done in general)?

Comment: you can always escalate the conversation to conference and then act as the conference manager

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea and I have actually started working on it as a "plan B", but it might be confusing for users seeing that they're joining a conference while they simply want to make a call. Another problem is that users won't get the "phone call experience" - ring-back tone in the beginning and a sound at the end of a call when caller/callee hangs up. In general it seems very strange to me that there is no way of making such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. As you establish a call, the call would have the state of "Established". Thats when you place a outbound call from your UCMA app, to a caller.
To make a B2B-Call, you need to have an incoming-idle state (one call is incoming while the other call is idle).

The way to do this is by establish a call, when its answered, then take that call object, and do a supervised transfer (aka 'Self-transfer') with that call. In that way you will return the same call as an incoming call, and by that it can be used as a call leg in a B2B call, which then can call Bob.

No need to escalate to a conference, unless you need that feature.